# switch case from a list of integers ,code optimization

Tags: c#, .net, optimization

i have a large switch case ,and i also have a list of integers say{1610616833,1610747905,1610878977,1610878977,1611010049}
i want to do the following

```
int a;
    switch (incomingint)
    {
    case 1:
    //some code
    break;

    case 2:
    //some code
    breakl

    //now i want to check if this one is one of the list's integers or not
    //so i did the following
    case 1610616833:
    a=0;
    break;

    case 1610747905:
    a=1;
    break;

    case 1610878977:
    a=2;
    break;
    }
```

The problem is :

1. I have around 16 element in the list
2. The code in the case of one of the list's members is almost the same except in the value i set for a .
   NOTE:
   setting the value of 'a' occurs only when the incomingint is one of the list members
   so instead of writing all of that code, is there any way to optimize this code??

Comment: it's very unclear what you are trying todo, it seems there are two thing asked and for the second, does this hold true: `a=(incomingInt-1000)`?

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dictionary for this transformation:

```
Dictionary<int, int> transformation = new Dictionary<int, int>
{
   { 1000, 0 },
   { 1001, 1 },

// etc

};

int a = 0; // Default value
if (transformation.TryGetValue(incomingint, out a))
{
   // a has the value. If you need to do something else, you might do it here because you know that dictionary had incomingint
}
```

Comment: Thanks Nikola but i dont set a in all cases ,the other cases has a different code :)

Comment: You said __except in the value i set for a__. If you have different branches you might complicate things by adding a class that would provide instructions for unified code how to behave for each incomingint.

Answer (score 2):

You can create a dictionary that will be a mapping between your list items and values of a.

```
var dict = new Dictionary<int,int>();
dict.Add(1000, 0);
dict.Add(1001, 1);
dict.Add(1002, 5);
...
```

And later:

```
a = dict[incomingint];
```

---

If there is a *direct* way to compute `a` from `incomingint`, just use `incomingint` in the calculation. The data you posted looks like you could simply do:

```
a = incomingint - 1000;
```

For `incomingint` of values 1000 and above.

Comment: This is not actually an optimization unless this switch case is executed many times, though.

Comment: Thanks Oded but i don't set 'a' in all cases ,the other cases has a different code

Comment: @SaraSaeed - It is difficult to give a comprehensive answer with the example you gave.

Answer (score 1):

it seems like you can optimize this by writing

```
if (incomingint > 1000) a = incomingint - 1000;
```

in other news, if you have 16 ints in a list, you almost definitely don't need to optimize it. that's a tiny, blazing-fast amount of work.

Comment: Thanks Alex but it's a simple imagination of the problem ,i'll edit the question again, the problem is that the numbers are not in sequence {1610878977,1610878977,..etc}